# save a favorite page in collection list based on cookies or local storage

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>New page name</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  /*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  /*
  * Erase cookie with name.
  * You can also erase/delete the cookie with name.
  */
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, '', -1);
  }
var faves = new Array();
  $(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; // current page url
    $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageTitle = $(document).find("title").text();
      var fav = {'title':pageTitle,'url':url};
      faves.push(fav);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });
    $(document.body).on('click','.remove',function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      faves.splice(id,1);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });

     var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
     faves = myfaves;
    $.each(myfaves,function(index,value){
      var element = '<li class="'+index+'"><h4>'+value.title+'</h4> <a href="'+value.url+'">Open page</a>  '+
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" data-id="'+index+'">Remove me</a>';
      $('#appendfavs').append(element);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>

  <ul id="appendfavs">

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to create a 'favorite' or 'save' button on each of the posts on my real estate site that will save the selected posts for later. It seems like a pretty standard feature on sites like Ebay, Autotrader, etc.and i want to use cookies or local storage to keep user favorites on that computer, which would allow users to add items to their favorites and see them again when they return. No account required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript and jQuery easily. use the below code to add to favourite the page that user is on and save it inside cookies and then fetch the list of pages saved as favourite.

i have made you a full file with which you can play around , inside the file i have created the functionality for `adding page` , `list pages` , `remove page` check it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>New page name</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  /*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  /*
  * Erase cookie with name.
  * You can also erase/delete the cookie with name.
  */
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, '', -1);
  }
var faves = new Array();
  $(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; // current page url
    $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageTitle = $(document).find("title").text();
      var fav = {'title':pageTitle,'url':url};
      faves.push(fav);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });
    $(document.body).on('click','.remove',function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      faves.splice(id,1);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });

     var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
     faves = myfaves;
    $.each(myfaves,function(index,value){
      var element = '<li class="'+index+'"><h4>'+value.title+'</h4> <a href="'+value.url+'">Open page</a>  '+
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" data-id="'+index+'">Remove me</a>';
      $('#appendfavs').append(element);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>

  <ul id="appendfavs">

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The page will look alike this :

[image]

`createCookie` This function will make new cookie inside user's browser with specified name , in your case the name is : `favespages` , you can use whatever name you want. it has 3 parameters , right now i'm using 2 parameters : `name` and `value` , `name` for cookie's name and `value` for the pages json object in which we store all of our fav pages. `days` parameters is used to specify an expiry period for specific cookie you are creating.

`readCookie` this function is used to get the cookie from user's browser where he is storing the fav pages. if user haven't any pages in favespages cookie then it will be empty. After getting the string from cookie , i need to convert that string back to an json object for printing the pages list. so for doing this i'm using `JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));`

For getting more familiar with this concept , you have to play around with the code and see what happens when you change something there n here.

Comment: thank you very much for your answering i have problem in understanding this code could you please explain me a little about functions you used again thank you

Comment: for example what this function do exactky 
function createCookie(name, value, days)

Comment: @user6362236 createCookie , makes cookie with specified name inside user's browser , or if the cookie with that name is already there , then it will update the cookie and new value that we have added. I have made comment on function to let you now , what this function is doing

Comment: thank you very much for your explanations.
i click on add me to fav but nothing happens which page this favorite results save. 
i mean i think i  have to specify a Destination page  which my favorite page go and save there?

Comment: This will add to fav the page you are on with it's url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114741/discussion-between-user6362236-and-arsh).

Comment: hi man how are u? this code is working great for me but recently i realized something. as you know this code is gonna save my page title and url after i click on `add to favorites` in cookies which it does it.

Comment: now consider  i visit one of my ads and click on "add to favorite" then if i open another page and then i read my cookie in "favorite page" i will see both of the pages title and url in my `favorite page` but consider i open two ads and then click on "add to favorite" on first ad and then go to second ad (without any refreshing) and click on "add to favorite" on second ad this time if i read my cookie in "favorite page" i will see just last ads title and url. how can i solve it

Comment: to sum up i want to Share Cookie among browser tabs without refreshing tab any idea?