# save page variables in local storage and show them in another page

Tags: javascript, php

I have an advertising website I show all my ads in a image gallery and if you click on each of them it goes to a view more page and you can get a lot more data about that ad.

```html
viewmore page
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
$price=$row['price'];
$room=$row['room'];
$parking=$row['parking'];
$floor=$row['floor'];
?>
```

I've the code in php like this. Now I want to add an option to my view more page and if a user clicks on a button like add this page to favorites the page variables `"price", "room", "parking", "floor"` save in local storage and display on certain pages which I named the favorite page and every time a user comes to the website he or she can go to the page and review selected pages easely, any idea?

Comment: You can check my answer here: [Save favorite page in cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37832664/4388034) , based on same kind of idea, it includes , `add page` , `remove page` , `list pages`

Comment: hi man thank you i add your answer to the question. are you sure it is correct because i add it to my websie and it did not work at all. i click on add me to fav and it did not show any thing.

Comment: are you sure the ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2 is correct

Comment: for me it worked always , till now , show me your console errors , and remember that , you have to make little edits to the code according to your needs. else it will not work as you are expecting it to work.

Comment: i did not add anything to your code i just wanted to check it first then edite it the way i want. also it did not give me any error i click on it it and it doesnot show anything. i check it in both google chrome and firefox

Comment: let me check again and post back as answer

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: why u delete the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LocalStorage:

> The localStorage property allows you to access a local Storage object. Data stored in localStorage has no expiration time. In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per domain.

An Example:

```
// Save data to the current local store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Access some stored data
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));

// Remove some data from Local Storage
localStorage.removeItem('username');

//json example
var car = {};
car.wheels = 4;
car.doors = 2;
car.sound = 'vroom';
car.name = 'Lightning McQueen';
console.log( car );
localStorage.setItem( 'car', JSON.stringify(car) );    //converts the 'car' object into a string and attaches it to the property 'car' of localStorage
console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'car' ) ) );  //logs an object
```

Here are some links you can follow to read more about the usage of local storage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

An Example:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

Hope this helps :)